# App Engine PHP errors on mysqli_connect

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mysqli

I've installed the App Engine PHP SDK for Linux and a separate PHP installation as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads).  I've started App Engine using `google_appengine/dev_appserver.py` with the included guestbook demo application.  When I run the application in the browser, I get the error

```
Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

There are two things that I can't understand regarding this error:

1. When I output `phpinfo()`, it doesn't list any php.ini as being used.
2. On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/), Google says that the mysqli extension is enabled by default.

I feel like I'm missing something in the App Engine SDK setup.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's PHP installation directions state that PHP needs to compile with the `--with-mysql` option.  However, the sample guestbook application uses mysqli so change `--with-mysql` to `--with-mysqli` when running `./configure ...`.  This solved it for me.